# Does User.generateVerificationToken persists the token to the database

Tags: loopbackjs

When calling [`User.generateVerificationToken(..)`](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-generateverificationtoken), is the generated token actually persisted in the database ?

I am not sure how to verify this because the [accessToken API](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#accesstoken) does not provide a way to get all tokens inside the database using the node API (which is I believe a matter of security ?)

Comment: Dumb question - but if you have access to the database, can't you just look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer is pretty simple.

In Loopback `User` `hasMany` `AccessToken`, so it is possible to do

```
User.__get__accessToken({}, function(err, tokens) {
  console.log(tokens);
  // ...
}
```

Using this method, I found that `User.generateVerificationToken` does not persist a model in the database.

Instead, the instance method [`user.createAccessToken`](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-prototype-createaccesstoken) does persist one.